# Material UI search to match the design

Tags: reactjs, search, input, material-ui, textfield

[image]

How can I build the search component that looks similar to the screenshot using Material UI components ?

```
 <TextField
            fullWidth
            variant="filled"
            label="Search"
            InputProps={{
              endAdornment: (
                <InputAdornment position="start">
                  <SearchIcon />
                </InputAdornment>
              ),
            }}
            id="search"
          />
```

Comment: Hello, it would be good if you could show us some code you already tried to do so we can help you !

Comment: Updated the request. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code for an (almost) full customisable Search field close on what you have at your example and the [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-customised-search-field-699kw4?file=/demo.tsx) to play with it.
I believe with this code it is easy to understand and make any additional changes.

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { styled, alpha } from "@mui/material/styles";
import InputBase from "@mui/material/InputBase";
import SearchIcon from "@mui/icons-material/Search";

export const Search = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  position: "relative",
  borderRadius: 9, //or use your theme.shape.borderRadius,
  backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15),
  boxShadow: "0 0 0 2px #919191 inset",
  color: "#2a2a2a",
  "&:hover": {
    backgroundColor: alpha(theme.palette.common.white, 0.15)
  },
  marginLeft: 0,
  marginRight: 0,
  width: "100%",
  [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
    marginLeft: theme.spacing(1),
    width: "auto"
  }
}));

export const SearchIconWrapper = styled("div")(({ theme }) => ({
  padding: theme.spacing(0, 1),
  height: "100%",
  position: "absolute",
  right: "0",
  pointerEvents: "none",
  display: "flex",
  alignItems: "center",
  justifyContent: "center"
}));

export const StyledInputBase = styled(InputBase)(({ theme }) => ({
  color: "inherit",
  "& .MuiInputBase-input": {
    padding: theme.spacing(1, 1, 1, 0),
    paddingLeft: `calc(1em + ${theme.spacing(0)})`,
    transition: theme.transitions.create("width"),
    width: "100%",
    [theme.breakpoints.up("sm")]: {
      width: "12ch",
      "&:focus": {
        width: "20ch"
      }
    }
  }
}));

export default function BasicTextFields() {
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");

  const handleSearch = (event) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    setQuery(value);
  };

  return (
    <Search>
      <SearchIconWrapper>
        <SearchIcon />
      </SearchIconWrapper>
      <StyledInputBase
        onChange={handleSearch}
        placeholder="Search"
        inputProps={{ "aria-label": "search", "data-testid": "searchField" }}
        value={query}
      />
    </Search>
  );
}
```